# Does VMware or VirtualBox use the same internal IP address as the host?

Tags: networking, virtual-machine

I would like to use my desktop computer to host a virtual local home server, and would like the internal IP addresses of my desktop computer and the virtual one to be different. Does VMware or VirtualBox use the same internal IP addresses for the host and the virtual machine?

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the network setting you set when you create the virtual machine. On VMware Workstation, the options below are available. I'm assuming that VirtualBox uses a similar approach:

- **Bridged:** The virtualisation software creates a virtual switch on the host computer that connects the virtual machine to the network as a separate individual. That means that the guest machine gets its own IP-address and uses the same DHCP-settings. It's a network participant equal to the host machine.
- **NAT (Network Address Translation):** The guest machine uses the host machine's IP-address. The virtualisation software's NAT service passes network data between one or more virtual machines and the external network.
- **Host-only or isolated networking:** The host computer sets up a virtual and usually isolated network that the host is connected to. The guest machine isn't linked to the host's network directly.

If you want your host and guest machine to have different IP-addresses but have them both on the same network, you should go for the **bridged** networking option.

For more detailed information on these configurations, you could check out the [VMware documentation](http://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-11/index.jsp#com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-D9B0A52D-38A2-45D7-A9EB-987ACE77F93C.html).